# FreeRTOS scheduler is not triggering the TASK

Tags: stm32, c, embedded, freertos, rtos

I am programming an STM32F103 for my project and recently switched from bare-metal to RTOS (FreeRTOS to be specific) without using CubeMX (code attached below.)

For now, I am simply running an LED toggling program using FreeRTOS with a single task activated. After the task is created successfully, the program stays inside the **vTaskStartScheduler()** infinite loop function but never toggles the LED.

Can someone please guide me on what the possible issue is? D I need to configure a timer (SysTick?) for the scheduler to work?

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include "FreeRTOS.h"   // ARM.FreeRTOS::RTOS:Core
#include "stm32f10x.h"  // Device header
#include "task.h"
#include "timers.h"
void DelayMS(volatile int);

void vTask2(void *);
BaseType_t check = 0;

int main()
{
    RCC->APB2ENR |= 0x0004;  // Enabling CLK for GPIOA
    GPIOA->CRL &= 0xFF0FFFFF;
    GPIOA->CRL |= 0x00200000;  // Declaring pin as OUTPUT

    check = xTaskCreate(vTask2, "Ho", 500, NULL, 1, NULL);  // creating the LED toggling task

    vTaskStartScheduler();
    return 0;
}

void vTask2(void *parameter)
{  // task to toggle LED
    while (1) {
        GPIOA->ODR |= 0x20;
        DelayMS(500);
        GPIOA->ODR &= ~0x20;
        DelayMS(500);

        //vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS( 500 ));
    }
}

void DelayMS(volatile int Delay)
{  // ms delay
    for (volatile int j = 0; j < Delay; j++) {
        for (volatile int i = 0; i < 7999; i++)
            ;
    }
}
`
```

Below is the FreeRTOSConfig.h file for STM32F103

```
/*
 * FreeRTOS Kernel V10.2.0
 * Copyright (C) 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates.  All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
 * this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
 * the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
 * use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of
 * the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
 * subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR
 * COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER
 * IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN
 * CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * http://www.FreeRTOS.org
 * http://aws.amazon.com/freertos
 *
 * 1 tab == 4 spaces!
 */


#ifndef FREERTOS_CONFIG_H
#define FREERTOS_CONFIG_H

/*-----------------------------------------------------------
 * Application specific definitions.
 *
 * These definitions should be adjusted for your particular hardware and
 * application requirements.
 *
 * THESE PARAMETERS ARE DESCRIBED WITHIN THE 'CONFIGURATION' SECTION OF THE
 * FreeRTOS API DOCUMENTATION AVAILABLE ON THE FreeRTOS.org WEB SITE.
 *
 * See http://www.freertos.org/a00110.html
 *----------------------------------------------------------*/

#if (defined(__ARMCC_VERSION) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__ICCARM__))
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint32_t SystemCoreClock;
#endif

/* Constants that describe the hardware and memory usage. */
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ                    (SystemCoreClock)
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ                    ((TickType_t)1000)
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE                 ((size_t)4096)
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE              ((uint16_t)256)
#define configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION      1
#define configSUPPORT_STATIC_ALLOCATION       0

/* Constants related to the behaviour or the scheduler. */
#define configMAX_PRIORITIES                  5
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION                  1
#define configUSE_TIME_SLICING                1
#define configIDLE_SHOULD_YIELD               1
#define configMAX_TASK_NAME_LEN               (10)
#define configUSE_16_BIT_TICKS                0

/* Software timer definitions. */
#define configUSE_TIMERS                      1
#define configTIMER_TASK_PRIORITY             2
#define configTIMER_QUEUE_LENGTH              5
#define configTIMER_TASK_STACK_DEPTH          (configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE * 2)

/* Constants that build features in or out. */
#define configUSE_MUTEXES                     1
#define configUSE_RECURSIVE_MUTEXES           1
#define configUSE_COUNTING_SEMAPHORES         1
#define configUSE_QUEUE_SETS                  1
#define configUSE_TASK_NOTIFICATIONS          1
#define configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY              1
#define configUSE_TICKLESS_IDLE               1
#define configUSE_APPLICATION_TASK_TAG        0
#define configUSE_NEWLIB_REENTRANT            0
#define configUSE_CO_ROUTINES                 0

/* Constants provided for debugging and optimisation assistance. */
#define configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW        0
#define configQUEUE_REGISTRY_SIZE             0
#define configASSERT( x )                     if( ( x ) == 0 ) { taskDISABLE_INTERRUPTS(); for( ;; ); }

/* Constants that define which hook (callback) functions should be used. */
#define configUSE_IDLE_HOOK                   0
#define configUSE_TICK_HOOK                   0
#define configUSE_DAEMON_TASK_STARTUP_HOOK    0
#define configUSE_MALLOC_FAILED_HOOK          0

/* Port specific configuration. */
#define configENABLE_MPU                      0
#define configENABLE_FPU                      1
#define configENABLE_TRUSTZONE                1
#define configMINIMAL_SECURE_STACK_SIZE       ((uint32_t)1024)
#define configRUN_FREERTOS_SECURE_ONLY        0

/* Cortex-M specific definitions. */
#ifdef __NVIC_PRIO_BITS
  /* __NVIC_PRIO_BITS will be specified when CMSIS is being used. */
  #define configPRIO_BITS                     __NVIC_PRIO_BITS
#else
  /* 7 priority levels */
  #define configPRIO_BITS                     3
#endif

/* The lowest interrupt priority that can be used in a call to a "set priority" function. */
#define configLIBRARY_LOWEST_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY       0x07

/* The highest interrupt priority that can be used by any interrupt service
 * routine that makes calls to interrupt safe FreeRTOS API functions.  DO NOT
 * CALL INTERRUPT SAFE FREERTOS API FUNCTIONS FROM ANY INTERRUPT THAT HAS A
 * HIGHER PRIORITY THAN THIS! (higher priorities are lower numeric values). */
#define configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY  5

/* Interrupt priorities used by the kernel port layer itself.  These are generic
 * to all Cortex-M ports, and do not rely on any particular library functions. */
#define configKERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY               (configLIBRARY_LOWEST_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS))

/* !!!! configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY must not be set to zero !!!!
 * See http://www.FreeRTOS.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html. */
#define configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY          (configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS))

/* Set the following definitions to 1 to include the API function, or zero
 * to exclude the API function.  NOTE:  Setting an INCLUDE_ parameter to 0 is
 * only necessary if the linker does not automatically remove functions that are
 * not referenced anyway. */
#define INCLUDE_vTaskPrioritySet              1
#define INCLUDE_uxTaskPriorityGet             1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelete                   1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend                  1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelayUntil               1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelay                    1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetIdleTaskHandle        1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskAbortDelay               1
#define INCLUDE_xQueueGetMutexHolder          1
#define INCLUDE_xSemaphoreGetMutexHolder      1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetHandle                1
#define INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark   1
#define INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark2  1
#define INCLUDE_eTaskGetState                 1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskResumeFromISR            1
#define INCLUDE_xTimerPendFunctionCall        1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetSchedulerState        1
#define INCLUDE_xTaskGetCurrentTaskHandle     1

/* Map the FreeRTOS port interrupt handlers to their CMSIS standard names. */
#define xPortPendSVHandler                    PendSV_Handler
#define vPortSVCHandler                       SVC_Handler
#define xPortSysTickHandler                   SysTick_Handler

#if (defined(__ARMCC_VERSION) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__ICCARM__))
/* Include debug event definitions */
#include "freertos_evr.h"
#endif

#endif /* FREERTOS_CONFIG_H */
```

Comment: As you can see in your `FreeRTOSConfig.h`, FreeRTOS is expecting that SysTick is running. (why else would it try to map the IRQ handler?). I don't see you configuring SysTick anywhere in your code.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for commenting. This was actually my question that whether I need to configure the SysTick timer or not. OK, after enabling the timer do I need to map it with any specific variable or just initializing it will do the magic ?

Comment: and which specific variable in FreeRTOSConfig.h expects me to specifically configure the SysTick timer and not any other.

Comment: The line: `#define xPortSysTickHandler                   SysTick_Handler` <- causes the FreeRTOS SysTick interrupt handler to be 'mapped over' the standard CMSIS SysTick_Handler. I don't know what you mean by "do I need to map it with any specific variable".

Comment: What is `check`? You assigned it an (important) value but never used it.

Comment: What do you mean with "_the program stays inside the vTaskStartScheduler() infinite loop function_"? There [is no infinite loop](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/main/tasks.c#L1968) in `vTaskStartScheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes not too much sense.

1. STM32F407 GPIO does not have CRL register. They are specific to the very old F1xx uC from STM. F4 has completely different peripherals and core M4 vs M3
2. You use wrong CMSIS file (`#include "stm32f10x.h"`)

I think that you have copy-paste the code from the F103 example and it will not work on your micro.

Comment: I was using both F103 and F407 to implement the same example. I pasted the code from F103 and mistakenly put the F407 name. I have modified it the name of controller. Is there something in the code which is wrong ?

Comment: @Noman for example you need to add readback, delay or barrier after enabling the gpio clock. BTW start from the reference manual.